# Programmatic nested numba.cuda function calls

Tags: python, cuda, numba

Numba & CUDA noob here. I'd like to be able to have one `numba.cuda` function programmatically call another one from the device, without having to pass any data back to the host. For example, given the setup

```
from numba import cuda

@cuda.jit('int32(int32)', device=True)
def a(x):
    return x+1

@cuda.jit('int32(int32)', device=True)
def b(x):
    return 2*x
```

I'd like to be able to define a composition kernel function like

```
@cuda.jit('void(int32, __device__, int32)')
def b_comp(x, inner, result):
    y = inner(x)
    result = b(y)
```

and successfully obtain

```
b_comp(1, a, result)
assert result == 4
```

Ideally I'd like `b_comp` to accept varying function arguments after it compiles [e.g. after the above call, to still accept `b_comp(1, b, result)`] -- but a solution where the function arguments become fixed at compile time will still work for me.

From what I've read, it seems that CUDA supports passing function pointers.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47810891/passing-functions-to-cuda-blocks-with-numba) suggests that `numba.cuda` has no such support, but the post isn't convincing, and is also a year old. The page for [supported Python in numba.cuda](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda/cudapysupported.html) doesn't mention function pointer support. But it links to the [supported Python in numba](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html#pysupported-builtin-types) page, which makes it clear that `numba.jit()` *does* support functions as arguments, although they get fixed at compile time. If `numba.cuda.jit()` does the same, like I said above, that'll work. In that case, when specifying the signature for `comp`, how should I state the variable type? Or could I use `numba.cuda.autojit()`?

If `numba` doesn't support any such direct approach, is metaprogramming a reasonable option? E.g. once I know the `inner` function, my script could create a new script containing a python function that composes those specific functions, and then apply `numba.cuda.jit()`, and then import the result. It seems convoluted, but it's the only other `numba`-based option I could think of.

If `numba` won't do the trick at all, or at least not without serious cludgery, I'd be happy with an answer that gave a few details, plus a rec like "switch to PyCuda".

Answer (score 3):

Here's what worked for me:

1. Not decorating my functions with `cuda.jit` initially, so that they still possess the `__name__` attribute
2. Getting the `__name__` attribute
3. Now applying `cuda.jit` to my functions by directly calling the decorator
4. Creating the python for the composition function in a string, and passing it to `exec`

The exact code:

```
from numba import cuda
import numpy as np


def a(x):
    return x+1

def b(x):
    return 2*x


# Here, pretend we've been passed the inner function and the outer function as arguments
inner_fun = a
outer_fun = b

# And pretend we have noooooo idea what functions these guys actually point to
inner_name = inner_fun.__name__
outer_name = outer_fun.__name__

# Now manually apply the decorator
a = cuda.jit('int32(int32)', device=True)(a)
b = cuda.jit('int32(int32)', device=True)(b)

# Now construct the definition string for the composition function, and exec it.
exec_string = '@cuda.jit(\'void(int32, int32[:])\')\n' \
              'def custom_comp(x, out_array):\n' \
              '    out_array[0]=' + outer_name + '(' + inner_name + '(x))\n'

exec(exec_string)

out_array = np.array([-1])
custom_comp(1, out_array)
print(out_array)
```

As expected, the output is

```
[4]
```